# App Pool Login Failed Message in New Acumatica Version

Tags: acumatica

I am using Acumatica 2018 R2 build 18.204.0013.

I have created a new instance on my local with Windows Authentication. However, when I launch the application, it gave me below error.

Error: - "Login Failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\apppoolname"

I have also other instances running different versions with Windows Authentication which are working fine but they are all upgraded from lower versions to the latest.

I have observed that if I create a new instance with SQL Authentication instead of Windows Authentication then it works. This started happening from 2018 R2 I think. Is there anything changed or any recommendation that we should be using SQL authentication always going forward from 2018 R2. Please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution. 
Create an instance with SQL Authentication and not Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

When creating the database using Acumatica ERP Configuration Wizard, an AppPool User is inserted in the database security settings:
[image]

The Login for user IIS/AppPool failed error can happen when you backup/restore a database for use with a different website that uses a different AppPool. It is a mismatch between AppPool used by the IIS website instance and the Database User in Security.

Adding the missing IIS/AppPool User in the database security should resolve the error. It is easier to create it from the UI using Microsoft SQL Management Studio. The user requires membership for 'db_datareader', 'db_datawriter' and 'db_ddladmin' role:
[image]

Comment: However, how this issue happens with new instance setup. I was not restoring any DB. Also IIS/AppPool user is also present.

Comment: It is difficult to determine without a complete view of the environment but it strongly looks like a security configuration issue between AppPool used by IIS and AppPool used by Database.

Comment: I agree with that. But how it could be as all other sites are running perfectly ok with Windows Authentication and with new site its working only with SQL Authentication.

Comment: My suggestion would be to compare metadata of working db to the one of the non-working one. Compare each user security settings. Also you can compare 'web.config' files and in IIS (inetmgr) advanced settings.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding the IIS AppPool user to the database as DBO in SSMS.  Adding it with db_datareader, db_datawriter, and db_ddladmin was causing another error when trying to log in to Acumatica.  I was having this issue on 18.115 and 18.116, new instance with no data.  It's like the Acumatica install did not set up the database permissions.